# Why does my PostgreSQL query improve when I disabled nested loop and what to do about it?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, join

The database used is PostgreSQL. I have a query that combines two tables and does a where search on some category and then does order by by some property. The table products has a 10+ million products. If I put a random name on category name that doesn't exist the query should return 0 rows and it does but the problem is that the query becomes super slow and starts executing for 80+ seconds when used with Order By but when I remove order by it is fast and only when I query for the category that doesn't exist. Planner decides to go through all the rows and it becomes super slow.

Query:

```
explain analyze SELECT p.* FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
WHERE pc.category_id = 'asf'
ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC LIMIT 21;
```

```
    Limit  (cost=1001.02..26849.88 rows=21 width=240) (actual time=35099.387..35396.240 rows=0 loops=1)
    ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1001.02..6249039.48 rows=5076 width=240) (actual time=35099.385..35396.237 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.00..6247453.56 rows=2115 width=240) (actual time=35061.491..35061.492 rows=0 loops=3)
            ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using idx_products_updated_at on products p  (cost=0.43..2596897.52 rows=5482982 width=240) (actual time=0.057..4123.748 rows=4563924 loops=3)
            ->  Index Scan using idx_product_categories_product_id on product_categories pc  (cost=0.56..0.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=13691771)
                Index Cond: (product_id = p.id)
                Filter: (category_id = 'asf'::text)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 1
    Planning Time: 1.157 ms
    Execution Time: 35396.346 ms
```

I tried to set SET enable_nestloop = off; and it started working perfectly again, but I don't know if it's a good thing to set this to off and if not how to avoid this problem? It only happens when I use a made up category it goes crazy on the speed, but when the category exists it is fast. The order by is the culprit as when I remove it, it starts going fast.

Comment: Since you select from one table only, there is no need to join the tables. Try to use an IN clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL chooses a plan that avoids an explicit sort, in the hope that enough results with the category can be found quickly.

First, make sure that you have an index on `category_id`.

If there are not too many existing categories, you can try to gather better statistics:

```
ALTER TABLE products ALTER category_id SET STATISTICS 1000;
ANALYZE products;
```

That should do the trick if there are no more than 1000 different categories.

Other than that, you can force PostgreSQL to use a different plan that uses an index on `category_id`. To do that, use something like

```
ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: Hey Laurenz Albe this worked, but I am curious, when i do NULLS LAST it forces sort, and then it searches for category_id in the middle table product_categories, and because it doesn't exist it finishes instantly. But why doesn't it always search by middle table, wouldn't that always be faster? I don't understand how does SORT make it work dfifferently

Comment: If PostgreSQL knew that there are no result rows, it would automatically choose the faster plan. But your execution plan shows that it estimates that 5076 rows meet the condition. That's why it goes wrong. Therefore, my first suggestion was to improve the estimate. Only if that does not work, using force is the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try using EXISTS subquery, if you use this query then there will be no need of direct joining of the tables or filtering by category.
Try the following code;

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM product_categories pc
    WHERE pc.product_id = p.id
    AND pc.category_id = 'asf'
)
ORDER BY p.updated_at DESC
LIMIT 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't share the DDL for both tables and their indexes, we can only guess that there isn't an index on category_id. And most likely you benefit most from a combination with product_id:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_product_categories_product_id_category_id
ON product_categories (product_id, category_id);
```

Give it a try, and please share the new query plan.